# Moving the cursor to the end in a Word document using VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, import, ms-word

In a using VBA Excel to combine several Word documents to a single large document. I am opening a Word template and want to add the content of other Word document at the end of the template document.
After opening the template I copy the content of another Word document to the clipboard and them want to paste the clipboard content at the end of the template.
After the paste command the complete template content is replaced by the clipboard content.

```
Sub ModulesSamenvoegen()
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Dim PadnaamNaarHandleidingen As String
Dim RegelCounter As Integer
Dim ModuleCounter As Integer
Dim TekstModule As Word.Document
Dim Template As String
Dim Taal As String
Dim blnStart As Boolean
Dim ModuleRange As Range


Template = PadnaamNaarHandleidingen & "\" & Taal & "\Templates\" & "Masterhandleiding " & Taal & ".dotx"

'Open Word template

On Error Resume Next
'Kijk of Word al draait
Set WordApp = GetObject(Class:="Word.Application")
If WordApp Is Nothing Then
' Start Word
    Set WordApp = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Het is niet gelukt Word te starten!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    blnStart = True
End If
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
WordApp.Visible = True
WordApp.Activate
WordApp.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize

'Open document
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=Template)
WordApp.Selection.EndKey

'Voeg alle module uit array samen
ModuleCounter = 1
For RegelCounter = 1 To AantalTekstModules
    Set TekstModule = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=PadnaamNaarHandleidingen & "\" & Taal &     "\Tekstmodules\" & ModuleNaam(ModuleCounter))
    TekstModule.Select
    TekstModule.Range.Copy
    TekstModule.Close
    WordDoc.Select
    
    WordDoc.Range.Paste

    ModuleCounter = ModuleCounter + 1
Next

'Sluit en bewaar het document
WordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=True

ExitHandler:
On Error Resume Next
If blnStart Then
'Als we Word hadden gestart, sluiten we het nu weer
    WordApp.Quit SaveChanges:=False
End If
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no need to either move the cursor or select anything. See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43339-combine-multiple-word-documents.html

Answer (score 0):

replace your select/copy/paste code with this

```
WordDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertAfter TekstModule.Content
```

This only copies text, no images and such.

Answer (score 0):

- `WordApp.Selection.EndKey` doesn't move the insert point to the end of the document. The default value of parameter `Unit` is `wdLine`. It should be `WordApp.Selection.EndKey wdStory`.
- `TekstModule.Content.Copy` copy the content (include shapes) of the doc.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Document.Content property (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.content?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158007337)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Selection.EndKey method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.endkey?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158663161)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
'Voeg alle module uit array samen
ModuleCounter = 1
For RegelCounter = 1 To AantalTekstModules
    Set TekstModule = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=PadnaamNaarHandleidingen & "\" & Taal &     "\Tekstmodules\" & ModuleNaam(ModuleCounter))
    TekstModule.Content.Copy ' copy it w/o select
    WordDoc.Activate
    WordApp.Selection.EndKey wdStory
    WordApp.Selection.TypeParagraph ' paste at the new paragraph
    WordApp.Selection.Paste
    TekstModule.Close ' close doc after paste
    ModuleCounter = ModuleCounter + 1
Next
```